# How to send Slack notification after a Jenkins pipeline build failed?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, slack

I have a pipeline groovy script in Jenkins v2.19. Also I have a
"Slack Notification Plugin" v2.0.1 and "Groovy Postbuild Plugin" installed.

I can successfully send "build started" and "build finished" messages.

When a build fails, how can I send the "Build failed" message to a Slack channel?

Comment: It seems to me the Slack plugin already has a "notify failure" checkbox. Do you use latest version of Slack plugin ?

Comment: @Riduidel, where you can see this checkbox?

Comment: I have a 2.0.1 version of the Slack Notification Plugin

Comment: Checkbox is visible on Slack plugin website : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin (see section "Project Configuration")

Comment: I have a Pipeline project: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/
It's have different configuration an does not have this options at all.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Just in case if in Declarative Syntax,**

Now, Jenkins provides `post`. You can check result at the end of pipeline.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-example

Using like:

```
pipeline {
    stages { ... }
    post {
       // only triggered when blue or green sign
       success {
           slackSend ...
       }
       // triggered when red sign
       failure {
           slackSend ...
       }
       // trigger every-works
       always {
           slackSend ...
       }
    }
}
```

It would be used in every `stage` also. See the document link please.

Comment: It is important to note that the OP uses a Groovy (AKA scripted) pipeline, whereas `post` can only be used in a declarative pipeline. You cannot mix both.

Comment: @beatngu13 Oh, yes, That is what I missed. Thank you

Comment: @Rakk - When I use `success` or `failure` I get an error `Error when executing failure post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding` . I'm using this in declarative pipeline

Comment: @Prr I'm not sure but guessing you are using in `build` object. It is only be in `pipeline` object.

Comment: that is half backed as post usually has some clean up routine that may fail and you will not get to the slack call as it should be done after all activities.

Comment: Very neat and clear answer.

Answer (score 45):

You could do something like this and use a try catch block.

Here is some example Code:

```
node {
    try {
        notifyBuild('STARTED')

        stage('Prepare code') {
            echo 'do checkout stuff'
        }

        stage('Testing') {
            echo 'Testing'
            echo 'Testing - publish coverage results'
        }

        stage('Staging') {
            echo 'Deploy Stage'
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            echo 'Deploy - Backend'
            echo 'Deploy - Frontend'
        }

  } catch (e) {
    // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
    currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    throw e
  } finally {
    // Success or failure, always send notifications
    notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
  }
}

def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
  // build status of null means successful
  buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'

  // Default values
  def colorName = 'RED'
  def colorCode = '#FF0000'
  def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
  def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"

  // Override default values based on build status
  if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
    color = 'YELLOW'
    colorCode = '#FFFF00'
  } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL') {
    color = 'GREEN'
    colorCode = '#00FF00'
  } else {
    color = 'RED'
    colorCode = '#FF0000'
  }

  // Send notifications
  slackSend (color: colorCode, message: summary)
}
```

Complete snippet can be found here [Jenkinsfile Template](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/fahl-design/koxKe)

Comment: Thank you, @Fahl-Design, I'll try this a bit later and will write result to you.

Comment: Great! enjoy ;) As you can see in that snippet you can add any other notification service after slackSend

Comment: I used your example. When I produce an exception the value buildStatus will be "FAILURE" instead of "FAILED". Why though?

Comment: Found out why. The assigned value is matched against possible values and if no match is possible "FAILURE" will be returned. See https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Result.java and https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Result.java#L150-L155.
For consistency I would then assign "FAILURE" in the catch block.

Comment: The build status should be called `SUCCESS`, not `SUCCESSFUL` (at least in the recent Jenkins, when put in always/post block).

Answer (score 32):

Based on [Liam Newman's blog post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/18/pipeline-notifications/), have a look at this cleaned up snippet for Slack only in *scripted* pipelines (declarative pipeline users scroll down). It uses original [Jenkins results](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Result.html), message formatting, better colors (based on [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/)), and some Groovy features like [default arguments](http://groovy-programming.com/post/511516055):

```
def notifySlack(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
    // Build status of null means success.
    buildStatus = buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESS'

    def color

    if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
        color = '#D4DADF'
    } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
        color = '#BDFFC3'
    } else if (buildStatus == 'UNSTABLE') {
        color = '#FFFE89'
    } else {
        color = '#FF9FA1'
    }

    def msg = "${buildStatus}: `${env.JOB_NAME}` #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}:\n${env.BUILD_URL}"

    slackSend(color: color, message: msg)
}

node {
    try {
        notifySlack()

        // Existing build steps.
    } catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        throw e
    } finally {
        notifySlack(currentBuild.result)
    }
}
```

The output will be something like this (play around with different formatting styles [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22username%22%3A%22jenkins%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23D4DAD%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22STARTED%3A%20%60my-job-name%60%20%231%3A%5Cnhttps%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.org%2Fmy-job-url%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23BDFFC3%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22SUCCESS%3A%20%60my-job-name%60%20%232%3A%5Cnhttps%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.org%2Fmy-job-url%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23FFFE89%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22UNSTABLE%3A%20%60my-job-name%60%20%233%3A%5Cnhttps%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.org%2Fmy-job-url%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22%23FF9FA1%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22FAILURE%3A%20%60my-job-name%60%20%234%3A%5Cnhttps%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.org%2Fmy-job-url%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%5D%7D%5D%7D)):

[image]

Maybe `env.JOB_NAME` contains encoded slashes (`%2F`) which can be fixed with `replaceAll("%2F", "/")`. Check out [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/beatngu13/c525e65bbf2ed4dbf10dfc1258152aea) to see how to notify HipChat as well.

If you have a *declarative* pipeline, have a look at the Jenkins documentation on ["Cleaning up and notifications"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/) or Liam Newman's follow-up post ["Declarative Pipeline: Notifications and Shared Libraries"](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/).

Comment: The article by Liam seems to not be available anymore.