# Jenkins Job Failure reason to slack

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, slack

I have a Jenkins 2 Pipeline with Slack integration. It is currently only showing JOB NAME and status. I also want to put some message in the slack as well like we get in build failure emails from Jenkins. Is there a variable which has this message which I can use ?

Comment: Please post the code  you use for sending slack notifications.

Comment: What do you mean by failure reason? Console output? Other than that you can only have build status

Comment: @Vitalii, i used the below link to setup the notification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140191/how-to-send-slack-notification-after-jenkins-pipeline-build-failed

Comment: @Vadim , yes i mean output or i can get the stage which failed from the pipeline