# Can't use Slack notifications with pipelines

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I don't have `post build actions` in pipeline projects in Jenkins. Because of this i can't configure slack notifications. I tried to create freestyle project and it is working with notification without problem because i have a field that called post build actions.

I don't know if i can setup pipeline project as same as freestyle project for slack web hook. So is there any way to run slack notifications with Jenkins pipeline project or setup slack notifications with pipelines?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140191/how-to-send-slack-notification-after-jenkins-pipeline-build-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below URL has the sample usage syntax:

https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/

Comment: Thanks, I will try and answer back to you with results